# Resize shapes with RaphaelJS

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, javascript, raphael

[Is it possible using RaphaelJS ?](http://kitchenplanner.ikea.com/US/UI/Pages/VPUI.htm) 
I mean just 2D part.

The only way I thought is to rewrite all paths proportionally and then resize them to fit inside my canvas container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
[From the raphael site](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#scale)

```
var c = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
// makes the circle 1.5 times larger
c.scale(1.5, 1.5);
// makes the circle half as wide, and 75% as high
c.scale(.5, .75);
```

Comment: A circle IS A path, just created for you. Check the Raphael source.